# What do we call this noun phrase?

Tags: noun-phrases

> "My dear Professor, surely a sensible person like yourself can call
>   him by his name? **All this 'You-Know-Who' nonsense** - for eleven years I
>   have been trying to persuade people to call him by his proper name:
>   Voldemort." Professor McGonagall flinched, but Dumbledore, who was
>   unsticking two lemon drops, seemed not to notice. "It all gets so
>   confusing if we keep saying 'You-Know-Who.' I have never seen any
>   reason to be frightened of saying Voldemort's name. (Harry Potter and
>   the Sorcerer's Stone)

It seems ‘all this ‘You-Know-Who’ nonsense’ make a main clause in the semantic aspect, and for-clause subordinate one showing the reason for the main clause. But there’s no verb in the seeming-main clause. What do we call this kind of clause or phrase? Is there just omitting of verb? Or can a noun phrase make a clause semantically like an absolute phrase?

Comment: This could be construed as [metanoia](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/explicitly-correcting-yourself-while-writing-how-appropriate-is-it/2570#2570) or [*anacoluthon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacoluthon).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"All this 'You-Know-Who' nonsense" is a [noun phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) and a type of [parenthetical phrase](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/8-types-of-parenthetical-phrases/) called an [interjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection).

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I don't know the formalities of grammar well, but it seems to me, that we could restate the "All this 'You-Know-Who' nonsense - for 11 years..." as one of these, without changing the meaning terribly:

"All this nonsense - for 11 years..."

"All of this ado - for 11 years..."

"This situation - for 11 years..."

Does rephrasing it like that suggest a proper name for it?

Comment: This does not answer the question.